# change compiler path in mibench benchmarks

Tags: ubuntu

I need to change default compiler path in mibench benchmark to path of a precompiled alpha cross compiler. Make file is as follow:

```html
FILE1 = basicmath_small.c   rad2deg.c  cubic.c   isqrt.c
FILE2 = basicmath_large.c   rad2deg.c  cubic.c   isqrt.c

all: basicmath_small basicmath_large

basicmath_small: ${FILE1} Makefile
 gcc -static -O3 ${FILE1} -o basicmath_small -lm
basicmath_large: ${FILE2} Makefile
 gcc -static -O3 ${FILE2} -o basicmath_large -lm

clean:
 rm -rf basicmath_small basicmath_large output*
```

I changed the path of gcc to the alpha compiler as below:

```html
basicmath_small: ${FILE1} Makefile
 PATH:=myfolder/bin/gcc -static -O3 ${FILE1} -o basicmath_small -lm
basicmath_large: ${FILE2} Makefile
 PATH:=myfolder/bin/gcc -static -O3 ${FILE2} -o basicmath_large -lm
```

but it returns me errors. My host processor is intel. I installed ubuntu 14.4 on vmware & I use cross compiler from gem5 page on my ubuntu:

[Alpha: gcc-3.4.3 , gcc-4.3.2, glibc-2.6.1 (NPTL,x86/64) , gcc-4.3.2, glibc-2.6.1 (NPTL,x86/32)](http://www.gem5.org/Download)